# error while loading shared libraries

Tags: bash, shared-libraries

Thank you guys answering my previous problem on [undefined reference to function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433984/undefined-reference-to-function-declared-in-h-file-c-language). As you suggested, the reason under the problem is not linking the libraries. Now I have generated the executable file with: (the version of my g++ and gcc is 4.4.5. I am using Ubuntu 10.10.)

```
g++ -o ex_addinst  ./ex_addinst.o -L/home/li/work/tools/lindo/lindoapi/bin/linux64 -m64 -llindo64  -lmosek64 -lconsub3 -lc -ldl -lm -lguide -lpthread -lsvml -limf -lirc
```

But there comes **another problem**, when I run the executable file with

```
./ex_addinst
```

errors appear: (I am not sure I should start a new problem or not currently....)

```
./ex_addinst: error while loading shared libraries: liblindo64.so.6.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But liblindo64.so.6.0 exists in the folder of the lib ~/lindoapi/bin/linux64 which contains following files:

```
libconsub3.so  libirc.so          liblindojni.so        libmosek64.so.5.0  lindo.par
libguide.so    liblindo64.so      liblindojni.so.6.0.3  libsvml.so         placeholder
libimf.so      liblindo64.so.6.0  libmosek64.so         lindoapivars.sh    runlindo
```

I have created a symbolic link between liblindo.so.6.0 and liblindo.so:

```
ln -sf liblindo64.so.6.0 liblindo64.so
```

There is '-llindo64' is the g++ command, so I thought  **liblindo64.so.6.0** should have been linked.
I have tried to change -L to -Llib, but doesn't help.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the directory where the `.so` files live in in runtime linker's search path.

You can do that by changing the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable like this:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:$HOME/lindoapi/bin/linux64
```

before starting your executable.

Comment: Thanks Mat, in the directionary HOME/.../lindoapi/bin/linux64, there is a lindoapivars.sh file, where the LD_LIBRARY_PATH has been modified as: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:HOME/li/work/tools/lindo/lindoapi/bin/linux64
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH.     But he problem still appears..

Comment: Is it `HOME` or `$HOME` in that string?

Comment: it is $HOME, sorry, my typo. As there is the content in lindoapivars.sh, I think this is not the right place to change this variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not going to install libraries currently under `/home/li/work/tools/lindo/lindoapi/bin/linux64` into a system directory (`/usr/lib`, `/usr/local/lib`, etc.), then it is better to simply link the application such that it will just work(TM):

```
gcc -o ex_addinst  ./ex_addinst.o \
  -L/home/li/work/tools/lindo/lindoapi/bin/linux64 \
  -Wl,-rpath=/home/li/work/tools/lindo/lindoapi/bin/linux64 \
  -m64 -llindo64  -lmosek64 -lconsub3 -lc -ldl \
  -lm -lguide -lpthread -lsvml -limf -lirc
```

This is preferable to always having to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, because

- other people can run your executable (without having to set
  `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) and,
- it doesn't slow down all the other applications (otherwise they will all search `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for `libc.so.6`, etc.)

The reason your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` setting didn't work (comment to Mat's answer) is that you used `HOME` where `/home` was intended.

Comment: thanks friend, with your suggestion, I added the library into ~/.bashrc: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$HOME/li/work/tools/lindo/lindoapi/bin/linux64, but the problem is still the same. Am I correct to change ~/.bashrc ? I think I am suing non-login shell so I think only ~/.bashrc is read.

Comment: it works now...so queer...I am so happy, thanks for your help! @Mat

Answer (score 1):

to sum the solution:

1. I add the path to ~./bashrc with:

   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:$HOME/.../lindoapi/bin/linux64
2. (after generating .o file)link the objective file with:

   g++ -o ex_addinst  ./ex_addinst.o -L/home/.../lindoapi/bin/linux64 -m64 -llindo64  -lmosek64 -lconsub3 -lc -ldl -lm -lguide -lpthread -lsvml -limf -lirc