# undefined reference to functions declared in lindo.h

Tags: eclipse, undefined-function

I have the same problem described in this post:

[undefined reference to function declared in *.h file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433984/undefined-reference-to-function-declared-in-h-file-c-language)

I am writing a C/C++ project Using Eclipse.

How can I solve the same problem?

I have tried going to:
Project -> properties -> c c++ build -> settings -> 
Tool Settings->Gcc c++ libraries -> libraries -> libraries (-l)

and adding the libraries in /lindoappi/bin/linux34.

but it does not work. I added the directory to:

Project -> properties -> c c++ build -> settings -> 
Tool Settings->Gcc c++ libraries -> libraries -> library search path

The console output is:

> **** Build of configuration Debug for project LINDO_test ****
>
> make all 
>   Building target: LINDO_test
>   Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
>   g++ -L/home/mario/lindoapi/bin/linux32 -o"LINDO_test"  ./src/LINDO_test.o ./src/test_001.o   -lliblindo
>   /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lliblindo
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make: *** [LINDO_test] Error 1

The folowing is a related post too:
[error while loading shared libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7455601/error-while-loading-shared-libraries)

Any other suggestions?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to:

Project -> properties -> c c++ build -> settings -> Tool Settings->Gcc c++ linker  -> libraries -> libraries (-l)

add the libraries as:
lindo64
mosek64
and whatever you need.

Then add:
Project -> properties -> c c++ build -> settings -> Tool Settings->Gcc c++ linker

Make sure .../lindoapi/bin/linux64
is in 
Project -> properties -> c c++ build -> settings -> Tool Settings->Gcc c++ linker  -> libraries -> Library search path (-L)

edit the command line pattern to:
${COMMAND} ${OUTPUT} ... -Wl,-rpath=/opt/lindoapi/bin/linux64 ${INPUTS}

for some reason Eclipse only allows 
-soname, --out-implib, and --output-def 
for Wl, so you have to do it manually in this way.
Is not clean, but it works.

I hope this is useful to other users too.

happy coding.